# How do I combined the results that I got from GBQ into a single string of text separated by commas?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, bigquery-udf

I have a row of populated data in GBQ. I would love to have all those values in a single cell, separated by commas.

Right now, the results come out like this:

```
| Column A | 
| aaa  | 
| bbb  | 
| ccc  |
```

I'd love to have the result of the query to be like:

```
| aaa, bbb, ccc |
```

Thank you so much in advance.

I tried String_agg function but I'm getting the following error:

> No matching signature for aggregate function STRING_AGG for argument types: INT64, STRING. Supported signatures: STRING_AGG(STRING); STRING_AGG(STRING, STRING); STRING_AGG(BYTES); STRING_AGG(BYTES, BYTES) at [1:8]

Comment: This is the query that I ran:

SELECT STRING_AGG(ManufacturerPartID, ',') AS ConcatenatedResults
FROM `mytable'`
WHERE IsCASegmentationTarget = 1